# Setting root path: wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I appreciate that this is a very common error in Ruby. I've just started learning Ruby on Rails but I've gathered that this basically comes from passing the wrong number of arguments to a method.

I was reading through the Ruby docs and it seems that the standard way to have your root path is to have a `PagesController` with a `main` view. In "routes.rb" I have:

```
root to: 'pages#main'
```

This is my `PagesController`:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def main

  end
end
```

From my understanding, `main` is the default route, which I am trying to access. I have a `main` method which doesn't take any parameters but somehow it is being passed one. Where am I going wrong here?

**Errors**:

```
ArgumentError in PagesController#main 
wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)

Rails.root: C:/RubymineProjects/ShoppingApp
```

**Full Trace**:

```
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:89:in `initialize'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:89:in `new'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:89:in `action_methods'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:36:in `action_methods'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/url_for.rb:25:in `action_methods'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:179:in `action_method?'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:230:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:17:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:14:in `method_for_action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:130:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__897547547__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call' 
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call' 
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call' 
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call' 
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call' 
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call' 
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call' 
railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call' 
railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call' 
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call' 
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call' 
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Could you please paste the error trace?

Comment: What's with the title? Are you actually getting this error (with this empty `main` action)?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm assuming so.

Comment: What are you assuming?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm actually getting that error.

Comment: Show the actual code that produces the error (and point out the line)

Comment: I don't mind downvotes, but it would be helpful if you explained why so I could improve the question.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Forgive me, I am new to Ruby, but is this not the code that produces the error.

Comment: @jumpingcode: show the stack trace then. It doesn't look like it's the right piece of code.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I believe I've added all of the information it has given me

Comment: I see. Hmm, that's weird. Is method `main` really empty? What if you remove root route and try accessing `pages/main` instead?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Identical error. There is definitely not anything within `main`

Comment: What about the view then? Is it empty as well?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The view has the standard `h1` and `p` that rails generates on creation.

Comment: I'm close to giving up. Maybe it's some windows-induced error. :/

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What happens if you rename the method to something else like `index` and adapt the route? Perhaps it is a naming conflict with one of the other `main` methods.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It seems that way. I checked with my other working app, and it's identical in how its set up so its a weird one. Thanks for all your help troubleshooting though

Comment: @spickermann same thing unfortunately

Comment: What does the template look like for views/pages/main.html.erb?

Comment: @BillTurner `<h1>Hello, World!</h1>`

Comment: Hmm, wow. I'm clueless too, then. Sorry :/ Has anything been added to application_controller.rb?

Comment: Solution: Don't use Windows

Comment: Hah, possibly. But really it shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does

```
root 'pages#main'
```

solve the problem? (In rails 4, the documentations don't mention a "to:")

Comment: Actually, it [does](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root). The "to:" is optional.

Comment: This makes no difference

Comment: @jumpingcode: With your posted code should be everything fine, then.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Except for me I was using a rails word that I shouldn't have been using.

In my routes.rb file:

```
root :to => 'static#main'
```

and I got the same error as you.

in static_controller.rb I had

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController

  def main
  end

  def blog
  end

  def about
  end

  def process
  end


end
```

the problem was the method named process. I changed it to myprocess and everything worked.

Rails is like your significant other. Really annoying and frustrating when there's something wrong but they won't tell you what, but incredibly awesome and fantastic when everything goes the way it should.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question. It's a localized Q&A with yourself. You've used process, which is a reserved keyword, main isn't and is the only method in my controller.